# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}( f\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+ f\left(x_0+\frac n{n^2}\right)-nf(x_0) )$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm doing an exercise in Real Analysis and I would like to have my proof check since I'm not 100% sure of it. The problem says to consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $x_0$ and with $f(x_0)>0$ (which I guess it's useless at this point but the exercise had other points in which it was necessary so I put it anyway). Then, we are asked to evaluate the following

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(f\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+ f\left(x_0+\frac n{n^2}\right)-nf(x_0)\right).$$

Here is how I would do it:

1. $f$ is differentiable and hence continuous at $x_0$;
2. We apply Taylor's Theorem at $x_0$, so that there is a neighborhood of $x_0$, $I=(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, and a function $h$ such that, for all $x\in I$,
   $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+h(x)(x-x_0)$$
   and $h(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow x_0$.
3. Now, if $n>\frac 1{\delta}$ then each of the $n$ points $x_0+\frac 1{n^2},\dots,x_0+\frac 1n$ are in $I$ so we can apply the previous point to get

$$f\left(x_0+\frac k{n^2}\right)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\frac k{n^2}+h\left(x_0+\frac k{n^2}\right)\frac k{n^2}.$$

4. Summing from $k=1$ to $k=n$ we get

$$f\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+ f\left(x_0+\frac n{n^2}\right)=nf(x_0)+\frac {f'(x_0)}{n^2}(1+\dots+n)+\frac 1{n^2}\left(h\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+nh\left(x_0+\frac 1n\right)\right)$$

5. Using the fact that $1+\dots+n=\frac {n(n+1)}2$ our original expression simplifies to

$$f\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+ f\left(x_0+\frac n{n^2}\right)-nf(x_0)=\frac {f'(x_0)}{n^2}\frac {n(n+1)}2+\frac 1{n^2}\left(h\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+nh\left(x_0+\frac 1n\right)\right).$$

6. Fix $\epsilon>0$, since $\frac {n(n+1)}{2n^2}\rightarrow \frac 12$ there is an $\bar{n}$ such that $n\geq \bar{n}$ implies that $\left|\frac {n(n+1)}{2n^2}-\frac 12\right|<\epsilon$. On the other hand, there is a $\delta'$ such that $|h(x)|<\epsilon$ on $(x_0-\delta',x_0+\delta')$. Since $x_0+\frac k{n^2}\rightarrow x_0$ and $\frac k{n^2}\leq \frac 1n$ we have that for $n>\frac 1{\delta'}$

$$\left|h\left(x_0+\frac k{n^2}\right)\right|<\epsilon.$$

7. By picking $n\geq\max\left\{\frac 1{\delta},\bar{n},\frac 1{\delta'}\right\}$ we obtain that

$$\left|\frac {f'(x_0)}{n^2}\frac {n(n+1)}2+\frac 1{n^2}\left(h\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+nh\left(x_0+\frac 1n\right)\right)-\frac {f'(x_0)}2\right|\leq$$

$$f'(x_0)\left|\frac {n(n+1)}{2n^2}-\frac 12\right|+\frac 1{n^2}\left|h\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+nh\left(x_0+\frac 1n\right)\right|<$$

$$f'(x_0)\epsilon+\frac 1{n^2}\left|h\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)\right|+\dots+\frac n{n^2}\left|h\left(x_0+\frac 1n\right)\right|<f'(x_0)\epsilon+\epsilon(1+\dots+n)=$$

$$=f'(x_0)\epsilon+\frac {\epsilon}{n^2}\frac {n(n+1)}2<f'(x_0)\epsilon+\epsilon\left(\frac 12+\epsilon\right).$$

8. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we can conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(f\left(x_0+\frac 1{n^2}\right)+\dots+ f\left(x_0+\frac n{n^2}\right)-nf(x_0)\right) = \frac {f'(x_0)}2.$$

Is my proof correct? Is there any smarter/shorter way to do that? Thanks is advance for any help!

Comment: I think is correct. Nice proof, btw.

Comment: Looks good.$\\\\$

Comment: @Ramanujan well it's a sequence so, what else could $n$ tend to?

Answer (score 1):

Something you could use is the fact that $\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{h(x_0+k)}{k}=0$ so there exists an $n_0$ such that $h(x_0+k)<k$ for $k<1/n_0$, since the limit is taken over $n$ and $\frac{k}{n^2}\leq\frac{1}{n}$ we have that there exists an $n_0$ such that $$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n ih\left(x_0+\frac{i}{n^2}\right)<\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i^2}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n1=\frac{1}{n}$$
For all $n\geq n_0$, that sequence converges to $0$, so $\lim_n\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}ih(x_0+\frac{i}{n^2})=0$